# Insert data from one database to another with different collation settings

Tags: sql-server, database, insert, collation

All

I'm trying to insert data from one database into another. The problem here is that both databases have different collation settings.

I have heard you could avoid this problem in your insert statement to "parse" the collation setting or something.

So the question is can I manipulate it in my insert statement (with a parse or something like that) without having to change the collation setting in my database?

Can anyone help me on this problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention what your exact problem is, your SQL Server version or edition, your current collations, the data type(s) you use in your tables, what natural language(s) your character data is in etc.

Anyway, collations affect query results, not storage, so it isn't clear from your description what your actual problem is. Copying (Unicode) data to a database with a different collation will not change the data in any way. But, when you actually query the data you might have to use a [COLLATE clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184391.aspx) to get the same results from both databases.

Alternatively, you can [change the collation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177439.aspx) at different levels within the database if you have the permissions to do it, but of course that might break existing queries in the second database.

In summary, if you must have consistent ordering/sorting of Unicode data and you cannot guarantee that all data are stored with the same collation, then you need to use the COLLATE clause in your queries.

Finally, it's possible you're actually talking about [code pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186356.aspx), not collations. In that case, please either correct this question to make it more accurate or submit a new one.